# Most frequent text value in Google Sheets problem with not occurring more than once

Tags: google-sheets, frequency, word-frequency

I'm having some problems getting the most frequent value I'm using a formula that works is the next one:

```
=INDEX(A1:A9,MODE(IF((A1:A9<>"")*ISNA(MATCH(A1:A9,$B$1:$B1,0)),MATCH(A1:A9,A1:A9,0))))
```

But in some column the data appears like this:

[image]

An error when the value is not occurring more than once I would like to add some condition but I've been trying with different formulas and I did't get better results some advices or formulas that I could use please?

Answer (score 1):

per column:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(A1:A9, 
 "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A order by count(A) desc"), 2, 1)
```

per range:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(A1:G9), 
"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc"), 2, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this but actually I didn't know how to paste it

Answer (score 0):

You can also the formula below:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10)),COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10),0)))
```

And later drag it across the row:

[image: after applying the formula]

The notable functions used for this are the following:

- `COUNTIF` which will return the prevalent number of occurrences;
- `MATCH` in order to match the predominant choice;
- `ARRAYFORMULA` which enables the display of values returned from an array formula into multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with arrays.

**Reference**

- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550);
- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378);
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275).

Comment: Actually it worked some time I think in some cases it shows me the empty values as the most frequent but I don't need the "" or empty value just the text ones